# Unable to get elements using XPathSelectElements

Tags: c#, xpath

I have the Xelement as follows.

```
<root type="object">
<meta type="object">
    <disclaimer type="string">XXXXX</disclaimer>
    <license type="string">http://open.fda.gov/license</license>
    <last_updated type="string">2015-05-31</last_updated>
</meta>
<results type="array">
    <item type="object">
        <term type="string">Oxygen</term>
        <count type="number">397</count>
    </item>
    <item type="object">
        <term type="string">Ibuprofen</term>
        <count type="number">301</count>
    </item>         
</results>
```

```
 IEnumerable<XElement> data = XRoot.XPathSelectElements("/root/results/item/term");
```

I have tried the above code, to get the array of term element. But i am getting null as the result. I have tried the code in XML tools and i got the result.But, still i am unable to get.

May i kindly know, whether i am missing something or where i am mistaking?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `XRoot`?  And your XML is missing a closing `</root>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
IEnumerable<XElement> data = XRoot.XPathSelectElements("root/results/item/term");
```

what is `XRoot`? you should call `XPathSelectElements()` on your xelement...

Comment: Hi. Thanks. It really works. I have used full path and in xml tools, i am getting the answer. May i kindly know the explanation for ur code.?

Comment: if results node is inside the root node then the xpath is : "root/results/item/term" which is the same as "./root/results/item/term", not "/root/results/item/term". This is how it works in C#